# Objective C RabbitMQ Client use headers while publishing messages

Tags: objective-c, header, rabbitmq, client, message-queue

I'm using RabbitMQ Client app. I can use simple publish and in fact I want to publish message to the server by using this simple publish (only queue, not exchange). 
But I also want to give headers as NSDictionary (or other object like it, I don't know). Since documentation of RabbitMQ is not enough for Objective-C I could not find how to do this. I'll give receiver's id, message type etc in this header and this is not my choice (i must send it in a way).

Is there anyone knowing how to accomplish this? I hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just answered a question about this over on the mailing list, but we will be adding instructions to the documentation soon. Apologies - this area isn't well documented.

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/Bw0Jz6zOgxM/w7BO8NORBAAJ